# How do I translate MongoDb query from SQL to NoSQL

Tags: sql, json, mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

How do I write this SQL command in NoSQL

```
SELECT regionname from Worldbank;
```

Comment: see mongodb [find() docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be :

```
db.Worldbank.find({}, {regionname:1})
```

if you want distinct list of a column :

```
db.Worldbank.distinct("regionname")
```

Comment: and what if its :
SELECT distinct regionname from Worldbank;

Comment: @RanaOmer see second query